# Shift one value of array values to the beginning

Tags: php, array

Given an integer `$value` in the range of `1, 2, 3`, I want to get an array that starts with `$value` and proceeds with the remaining two integers from above in arbitrary order. The best I could think of was doing something like this:

```php
switch ($value) {
      case '1':
        $array = [1,2,3];
        break;

      case '2':
        $array = [2,1,3];
        break;

      case '3':
        $array = [3,1,2];
        break;
    }
```

Is there a shorter and more beautiful way of doing that? Something like that:

```
$array = push_to_top_of_array($value,[1,2,3]);
```

Comment: I should have asked earlier... how is `$array` used after this code? would there ever be a case where other values would exist in that array?

Comment: @SamOnela the array goes through a `foreach` loop. There is no case where other values would exist.

Comment: Okay- what does the `foreach` loop do with it? Can you describe the output of the script? For code review, it is best to have a broad picture of what the code does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a shorter and more beautiful way of doing that?

- shorter: yes
- more beautiful: well, that sounds subjective... you can be the judge of the approaches below.

One approach would be to take off the value using `$index` with [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/array_splice) and then put it (the first element from that spliced array) at the beginning using [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/array_unshift):

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
array_unshift($array, array_splice($array, $value - 1, 1)[0]);
```

[See it demonstrated in this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/XToWO0PHPBWN9kAi).

Another approach would be to merge the spliced array and the original array using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$array = array_merge(array_splice($array, $value - 1, 1), $array);
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/4eyLj4RcAkrW8U1y).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, for three array elements you can write:

```
$arr = [
    ($value - 1) % 3 + 1,
    ($value + 0) % 3 + 1,
    ($value + 1) % 3 + 1
];
```

The main ingredient here is the `$value modulo 3` expression. The above code contains some redundancies, which I have kept to clearly show the construction of the code. If you absolutely need faster code instead of readable code, the above is equivalent to:

```
$arr = [
    $value,
    $value % 3 + 1,
    5 - $value - $value % 3
];
```

Or, the brute force variant:

```
// To be executed only once in the program.
$arrs = [[], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]];

// And then, whenever you need it:
$arr = $arrs[$value];
```

Answer (score 5):

I hate hardcoded solutions and prefer generalized ones. You never know when your array will get a 4th element and break all the application.

So a generalized solution would be like

- get a key for the desired value
- remove this element from array
- add its value to the beginning of an array

in PHP it would be like

```
function push_to_top_of_array($value, $array) {
   $key = array_search($value, $array);
   if ($key === false) {
       throw new \OutOfRangeException("Value not found"); 
   }
   unset($array[$key]);
   array_unshift($array, $value);
   return $array;
}

$value = 2;
$array = [3, 5, 2, 4];
$array = push_to_top_of_array($value, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if "more beautiful" means you want a one-liner, but here are two more concise ways to perform the task:

*note, this doesn't validate the `$value` as being one of the element values -- if this is a necessary component of your project, then please clarify in your question.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/krc2G))

```
$value = 2;
$array = [1, 2, 3];
array_unshift($array,$value);  // prepend a duplicate
var_export(array_unique($array));  // kill the original

echo "\n---\n";

$value = 2;
$array = [1, 2, 3];
var_export(array_unique(array_merge([$value],$array)));  // prepend a duplicate, kill the original
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 1,
  3 => 3,
)
---
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 1,
  3 => 3,
)
```

On huge arrays, statistics have shown `array_flip(array_flip())` out performs `array_unique()` but that would certainly be less beautiful and if you were dealing with big array I'm sure you would have mentioned that.